# sending calender invitation as mail attachment in java mail API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, attachment, icalendar

I am creating icalender invitations in my java code dynamically. Now I want to send this icalender invitation as attachment in a mail without saving it to my server as file.

How can I achieve it?

My Code is:

---

```
public static void sendNow(String subject, String[] toArray, String[] ccArray, BodyPart bodyPart, BodyPart headerPart, List <MimeMessage> attachments ) {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(getMimeSession());
            // Add From Email id
            // Add TO receipients
            // Add CC receipients
            // SET Subject

            // Create a Multipart
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            if (null != bodyPart) {
                multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
            }
            if (null != headerPart) {
                multipart.addBodyPart(headerPart);
            }
             // Attaching MIMEMessage as attachment - IT IS NOT WORKING
                if(null != attachments) {

                //attach meeting invitation
                for (MimeMessage attach : attachments) {
                    message.setDataHandler(attach.getDataHandler());
                    message.setFileName(attach.getSubject() + ".ics");
                }
            }
            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // SEND
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Generate the data in memory and use [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) with a DataHandler to attach it to the message.